# Facebook IOS SDK requestWithGraph not posting message

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Every parameter gets posted properly except the little message blurb from the user (the 'message' parameter). How come this part of the post doesn't show in facebook? Am I setting the parameters wrong?
Please check out this image to see which part of the post I'm talking about:
https://skitch.com/hahmadi82/8uecw/brenton-joynin

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has invited you (%@) to enjoy an offer at %@ on %@", [nameArray objectAtIndex:0], [facebookNameArray objectAtIndex:i], spotString, timeChosenString], @"name",
                                                       domain, @"link",
                                                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", offerString, peopleString], @"caption",
                                                       @"Going out? Use JoynIn to grab amazing offers from local bars, clubs, and restaurants. All you need to bring is friends!", @"description",
                                                       titleChosen.text, @"message",              
                                                       nil];
                        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed/",[facebookUIDArray objectAtIndex:i]] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, "how come" is what kids say. LOL  Sorry.  Second, this is posting to another User's feed.  So you should be checking their wall for the post, not your wall.

I believe you have to include description.  Here is the code we use.  Seems like your code should work.  You should also check to make sure you have a proper Facebook ID in your %@ formatter.

```
NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"FACEBOOK_INVITE_MESSAGE", nil);
NSString *link = @"http://www.facebook.com/trivialapp";
NSString *description = NSLocalizedString(@"FACEBOOK_INVITE_DESCRIPTION", nil);
NSString *picture = @"http://trivi.al/Content/images/icon72.png";
NSMutableDictionary *tParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                message,     @"message",
                                link,        @"link",
                                description, @"description",
                                picture,     @"picture", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", [playerDict objectForKey:@"id"]] 
                      andParams:tParams
                    andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Facebook sessionValid? Ask with if statement:

```
     if (facebook isSessionValid) {
NSLog (@"Working fine..."); // it might also be better to place the post method in here and put an else statement to open a alert where it says error or something like that
}
```

if not.... check your methods like

handleOpenURL and fbDidLogin

Log there and see if called.... if not I had a very similar problem... Ill guide you through

So my problem was I should have declared the Facebook variable in the App Delegate... watch this.. this is watch you should do:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
fbAppDelegate = (NerdfeedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[[fbAppDelegate facebook] authorize:nil];// or wherever you wanna put it...
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   }

   -(IBAction)post {

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has invited you (%@) to enjoy an offer at %@ on %@", [nameArray objectAtIndex:0], [facebookNameArray objectAtIndex:i], spotString, timeChosenString], @"name",
                                                   domain, @"link",
                                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", offerString, peopleString], @"caption",
                                                   @"Going out? Use JoynIn to grab amazing offers from local bars, clubs, and restaurants. All you need to bring is friends!", @"description",
                                                   titleChosen.text, @"message",              
                                                   nil];
                    [fbAppDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed/",[facebookUIDArray objectAtIndex:i]] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];



   }
```

App Delegate.h:

```
    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate,    FBDialogDelegate, FBLoginDialogDelegate, FBRequestDelegate> 

   {

  Facebook *facebook;

  }


  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
```

App Delegate.m:

```
      static NSString *kAppID;
      - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
 return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
   }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
 }
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
  kAppID = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"//app id"];
   // ....
   facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:(id)self.viewController];
      [facebook setSessionDelegate:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
      facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
      facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

return YES;
   }


- (void)fbDidLogin {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];    
       }

  -(void)fbDidLogout {


// Remove saved authorization information if it exists
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
   }
  }
```

Comment: every parameter in my post works fine except the message. so the issue is not that it isn't posting, it's posting everything but the little message comment from the user. my guess is that i'm not setting up the parameters properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to publish a message with the post dialog actually thats not possible , i faced the same problem and i found this in Facebook documentation

> This field are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling
>   this field erodes the authenticity of the user voice.

Comment: i'm not sure why that's the case... with the php facebook library i'm able to post these messages with all the parameters using our website. it's the ios sdk that's not letting me do the same.